# Researcher applying for UK Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

Are UK Government strict towards researcher whose sole purpose of visit is for tourism?

Comment: Hi welcome to travel.SE! Is that a hypothetical question, or have you actually received a refusal? I assumed the former and edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Im going to apply soon, not for business visa but for standard visitor visa (tourism)

Comment: the standard visitor visa allows some non tourism activities. Are you attending a conference or something similar?

Comment: Im not attending a conference or going there related to work, just pure tourism only

Comment: @Mike Your question isn’t very clear. It reads as if you want to visit the U.K. for research purposes. If your proposed visit is just for tourism (a primary purpose of the Standard Visitor Visa https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), do you have a specific question about applying or eligibility that’s not answered by the published information?

Comment: im going to uk for tourism purposes only. I just wanted to know if UK govt is strict for researcher or it may affect my application because of the nature of my job

Comment: @Mike Why do you think being a researcher might be a problem? Can you prove your employment and income? I don’t recall seeing any questions on TSE where the type of job was a reason for refusal (although there are plenty where being unemployed, not being able to prove income etc resulted in a refusal). There’s nothing about job type restrictions in https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page2

Comment: Because Ive read some blogs, some says because their intention is doing some research

Comment: should apply for standard visitor visa? @Traveller

Comment: Yes. You have no other option. There is no researcher tourism visa.

Comment: @Mike I’m sorry, I still don’t understand your dilemma. You say your visit is for tourism only (defined as eg holiday/leisure/sightseeing, visiting friends/family) and that you are employed as a researcher (but your purpose in visiting isn’t to do research). On paper you therefore meet some of the eligibility criteria, in practice to apply you have to prove your employment, income, intention to leave etc.

Comment: thank you @HankyPanky just wanted to know if my nature of job affects my application. Im not going to uk for business/training/. Just purely tourism

Comment: Nope it doesn’t.

Comment: @HankyPanky It could conceivably matter a little bit in a *really* loose sense. If your job is one which you can "take with you", or do remotely, then it's a little bit less of a proof of ties to your home country. However, that shouldn't matter if the rest of the application isn't unusual.

Comment: Please edit your question to resolve the confusion here

Answer (score 3):

Under ‘Business - General Activities’, gathering information for a visitor’s employment overseas is a permitted activity (see App3, 5A https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes I know, but the original question was different. It’s been edited since I answered

Comment: Sorry. Didn't check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to the UK only for tourism, and not intending to do anything work-related in the UK, then it does not matter what your job is.

The job you have might affect your chances of getting a visa. If your job is much higher paid in the UK than in your country there might be a suspicion that you were trying to relocate illegally to the UK. If your job is low-level, or temporary, or easy to transition out of, then it is not considered as much of a tie to your home country as a well-paid long-term in-demand job. If your job is one where a visit to the UK would often be a part of your work, you might have to provide extra evidence to show that you will not be working.

The job title of 'researcher' is far too vague for us to comment upon whether that applies to you.